# Use custom font in Android WebView

Tags: android, android-webview, android-typeface

I want to use custom font that downloaded under data/data, in Android WebView.
I found the way of using custom font under assets, but under data/data is not.
I did Same things in iOS.
Do you have any idea?? thanks.

Comment: what u actually want....? the html content which u are loading on webview..does u want to change the font-type?

Comment: Thanks, I want to run paint engine created with javascript in WebView, it will use the fonts put under data/data, and managed Android application.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use Fonts from sdcard or data/data directory.

Try this way

```
Typeface.createFromFile("String file path of font");
```

**For Webview**

Create one css file in asset folder. Say **weblayout.css**

```
@font-face { 
font-family: 'myfont'; 
src: url('path to data/data');
}

body {
font-family: 'myfont';
}
```

Comment: You mean you want custom font in your script?